# An image at a specific point in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to place a .png image(firm logo) at a specific point(coordinate). I've put several buttons, one after another, and now I want the image to be displayed just below these buttons. The code below should do the trick, but the coordinates are simply not working.

```
//QLabel myLabel; QVBoxLayout *layout; // class members, initialized with 'this'
QPixmap pixmap("v.png");
myLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
myLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());
myLabel.setGeometry(QRect(312, 454, 21, 20));
layout->addWidget(&myLabel);
```

How should I modify the code to simply include this image, possibly at a specific coordinate (just as with QPushButton)? Note that commenting out the last line removes the image, but, even when the image is shown, the buttons cannot be clicked (and they are not part of 'layout') Please provide code that would achieve image positioning with given coordinates.

Comment: Is `myLabel` a member variable of the class? Is the path of the image correct?

Comment: How did you add buttons? With code or in Qt Designer?

Comment: Where `v.png` is located? How do you use `myLabel` then?

Comment: @thuga I've put myLabel as a member of the class, and added QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);, and layout->addWidget(&myLabel). The image is shown, but the coordinates do not seem to affect the position.

Comment: @user3560285 This is because of the layout. You can't use `setGeometry` when your widget is inside a layout.

Comment: In your question it is stated that the image is not shown, now you say that image is shown? Where is the true?

Comment: @Ezee The question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLayout` is a controller which position widgets added to it.  That is why it has no any sense to set coordinates to a widget and then place it to a layout. The layout will change the widget coordinates as soon as the widget is shown.

Futhermore, if you ask how to set certain position in coordinates, you shouldn't use `QLayout` at all, because it will change any position you set.

```
QPixmap pixmap("v.png");
myLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
myLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());
myLabel.setFixedSize(21, 20);
myLabel.move(312, 452); //ensure that this coordinates are in you widget
myLabel.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either show the label or put it in a layout or make sure it was given a parent in the constructor.

```
myLabel.setParent(parent_window)
```

The setParent method might also need you to show.

```
myLabel.show()
```

or

```
layout.addWidget(myLabel)
```